# Showing ads in the specific category and its sub-categories

Tags: plugins, theme-development

I would like in each category and sub-category of its own ads to be displayed. I used the in_category function but not displayed Advertising in sub-categories.

Please advice.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using and some more information about how to reproduce the issue?

Comment: i use `<?php is_category("Cat_ID"); ?>` for out of the loop and use `<?php in_category("Cat_ID") ?>` for inside the loop

Comment: Please, add the code to the question itself, it easier to read and any other person interested in answer the question will find it quickly than in comments. `is_category` is for check category archive pages, nothing to do with categories which a post belong to. Please, as I asked before, provide a full sample code and describe how it doesn't work; with the current information is very difficult to know why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category), `in_category()` checks categories directly assigned to the post. That means that if a post is assigned to a child category but not to the parent, using `in_category()` with the parent category will fail.

Example: you have the category with ID 10, which is child of category 9. The post is assigned to category 10, not to 9. The following code will check as false because `in_category()` checks categories directly assigned to the post:

```
if( in_category( 9 ) ) {

    // ...

}
```

If you want check if the post belongs to category 9 or any of its childs, you could use the `post_is_in_descendant_category` function defined as example in the `in_category` documentation:

```
if( in_category( 9 ) || post_is_in_descendant_category( 9 ) {

    // Post belongs to category 9 or any of its childs.

}

function post_is_in_descendant_category( $cats, $_post = null ) {
    foreach ( (array) $cats as $cat ) {
        // get_term_children() accepts integer ID only
        $descendants = get_term_children( (int) $cat, 'category' );
        if ( $descendants && in_category( $descendants, $_post ) )
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But as I said to you in the comments, I can not know what your exact problem is with the given information.